# Codeception: Webdriver could not be found and loaded

Tags: selenium, webdriver, yaml, codeception

I am having some issues running Codeception with Selenium on Windows 8 at my new job.

I get this error: 
[Codeception\Exception\Configuration]
Webdriver could not be found and loaded.

I started the Selenium server manually like I described last time in this post: [Web Driver Curl Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858818/web-driver-curl-exception/26997380#26997380)

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Edit - Some more info:

I am running WAMP server. 
I have configured a Virtual Host in httpd-vhostsconf
I have verified that the Selenium server is started. I tried to run the codeception test with and without the server started, in both cases I get the exact same message.

This is the content of acceptance.suite.yml:

```
modules:
  enabled:
    - Webdriver
    - AcceptanceHelper
  config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.dev/'
    Webdriver:
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.dev/'
        browser: firefox
```

Comment: which browser are you trying to run it on?

Comment: I am trying to run it on Firefox

Comment: please paste the webdriver module section in your suite yml file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So look like the problem is mistake in the module name, it should be `WebDriver` instead of `Webdriver`

Try running with:

```json
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
    - AcceptanceHelper
  config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.dev/'
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://www.mywebsite.dev/'
        browser: firefox
```

It should work.

Comment: Wow, just a stupid typo, I really didn't see it. Thanks, it works now. (test fails but that's another problem :) )

Comment: Cheers! Happy testing