# How to use dusk with laravel to crawl the web properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I have read that crawling pages with other http crawlers doesn't work well because they do not allow all sort of javascript. So firing up a browser and actually running it via the browser seems like the best option for a more advanced web page.

I read, that it seems to be working to run on servers without GUI even here: 
[Running Laravel Dusk on Headless (no GUI) machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174749/running-laravel-dusk-on-headless-no-gui-machine)

Now dusk is used in laravel for unit tests. But I want to use it in proper code and routes.

**How can I include and run dusk from a normal laravel route?**

btw: why? our app is making use of a third party app that does not offer an API. Simple things as "create new user" have to be done manually and the users of our platform have to wait until we manually create a login for them on the other platform. This is bad UX. So we want to automate it.

Comment: just read here that there seems to be a bunch of problems... i wonder if there is a solution
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/is-it-possible-to-use-laravel-dusk-browser-outside-of-testing

Comment: hacky solution, but you could create an acceptance test to visit the pages using the headless browser, and put your scraping code in there